# strlcat(): is dst always NUL_terminated? What are "size" and the returned value?

Tags: c

I have to implement my own version of the strlcat() function from the standard C library.

```
size_t     strlcat(char * restrict dst, const char * restrict src, size_t size);
```

I have two questions about how it works :

## Does it NUL_terminates `dst` in every case?

In my man I have the following :

> strlcat() take the full size of the buffer (not just the length) and
>   guarantee to NUL-terminate the result (as long as size is larger than 0 or, in the case of strlcat(), as long as ther is at least one byte free in dst).

and :

> The strlcat() function appends the NUL-terminated string src to the
>   end of dst.  It will append at most size - strlen(dst) - 1 bytes,
>   NUL-terminating the result.

but also :

> Note however, that if strlcat() traverses size characters without
>   finding a NUL, the length of the string is considered to be size and
>   the destination string will not be NUL-terminated (since there was no
>   space for the NUL).

So, should I NUL_terminate dst in EVERY case?
On one hand it says there is a case where the `dst` string isn't NUL_terminated.
On the other hand the man says that `strlcat()` guarantees that `dst` will be NUL_terminated, and wouldn't a non NUL_terminated string be pretty insecure?

Could someone give me an example where this case would occur?

## What does the returned value represents and why is there this behavior?

Here are the results I get with some tests :

```
Before :                || After :
dst   | src   | size    || dst      | return
------------------------||--------------------
dst\0 | src\0 | 0       || dst\0    | 3
dst\0 | src\0 | 1       || dst\0    | 4
dst\0 | src\0 | 2       || dst\0    | 5
dst\0 | src\0 | 3       || dst\0    | 6
dst\0 | src\0 | 4       || dst\0    | 6
dst\0 | src\0 | 5       || dsts\0   | 6
dst\0 | src\0 | 6       || dstsr\0  | 6
dst\0 | src\0 | 7       || dstsrc\0 | 6
dst\0 | src\0 | 8       || dstsrc\0 | 6
```

From the man again :

> [The strlcat() function] return the total length of the string [it
>   tries] to create. For strlcat() that means the initial length of dst
>   plus the length of src.

`dst`'s and `src`'s sizes are constant in my tests (3 and 3).
So why are there cases where the returned value is different from 6?

Isn't it rather `(len(dst) + min(size, len(src))`?

What does size represents?

> The strlcat() function appends the NUL-terminated string src to the
>   end of dst.  It will append at most size - strlen(dst) - 1 bytes,
>   NUL-terminating the result.

So size should be the the length ('\0' char included) `dst` is allowed to be at the end? Is that right?

Comment: *"Does it NUL_terminates dst in every case?"* not according to the third paragraph below where you asked that question. If you have to implement it, I suggest it should behave as documented.

Comment: `strlcat` is not in Standard C

Comment: @M.M I don't know, if I run `man strlcat` I have this in "library section" : **Standard C Library (libc, -lc)**

Comment: @vmonteco bad terminology. Check the C Standard to see what is in Standard C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### 1. Does strlcat always null-terminate `dst`?

`dst` will be null-terminated by `strlcat` if `strlcat` modifies `dst`. Strlcat does not modify `dst` if `dst` is already fully occupied. `dst` is considered fully-occupied if no `NUL` is found in the first `size - 1` bytes of `dst` (or if `size` is 0).

So there are two cases in which `dst` will not be null-terminated by `strlcat`. One is that `dst` is a null-terminated string of exactly `size - 1` bytes, in which case it is not modified and continues to be null-terminated. The second case is that `dst` was not null-terminated initially, and in that case it will still be unterminated after the call to `strlcat`.

#### 2. How is the length of the original destination string measured?

`size` is expected to be the size of the memory region containing `dst`, so that `dst[size]` is assumed to be an invalid memory reference. Consequently, if `dst` starts out as a valid (and therefore null-terminated) string, its length will be strictly less than `size` and `strlcat` will use `strlen(dst)` as its length. If `dst` is not valid, then its size is assumed to be `size` for the purposes of the return value. In this case, `dst` will not be modified. See above.

Comment: That's pretty clear, thank you! But can you please confirm (or invalidate) what I guess about the return value? :)

Comment: @vmonteco: i thought it was evident from my answer. It is `min(size, strlen(dst)) + strlen(src)` with the understanding that it only looks at a maximum of size characters to compute the left-hand expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think the returned values is `strnlen(dst) + strlen(src)` not `min(size, strlen(dst)) + strlen(src)`.
That's because `strlen(dst)` would access an invalid memory when `dst` is not null-terminated.